# How to solve Paperclip <NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, windows-10, paperclip

I'm trying to send a base64 encoded image to my rails server. The rails uses Paperclip for handling images (I don't really know much about the backend as I'm only developing a mobile application using ionic 2 and the API endpoints provided). I'm on a windows 10 machine, However everytime I try to send an image via a POST request I get this error.

```
[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #
<Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError: 
Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError>
```

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: what are the allowed image extensions and which is yours?

Comment: jpeg, gif 
I'm trying with jpeg...

Comment: u need to check if it's a valid jpeg, try other images too..

Comment: I've already validated the image by converting base 64 to image using a convertor and vice versa

Comment: Make sure that you have installed `ImageMagick` and set its path in development.rb as : `Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "your_image_magick_bin_path"`.